# MySQL - CaseSensitive: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a table `Customer` which is having foreign key constraint of `CustomerType(CustomerTypeId)`.

Now using EntityFramework when I try to insert record in `Customer` table I get an error saying

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ("Event"."Customer", CONSTRAINT "customer_ibfk_2" FOREIGN KEY ("CustomerTypeId") REFERENCES "CustomerType" ("CustomerTypeId"))

While researching on this error, I found that in MySQL database it is case sensitive and because of that I am getting this error.

Is there any possible solution to ignore case sensitivity in MYSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use *lower* function everywhere. Another solution, that is better, you have to fix your database. Change your foreign key, or table, or just create table again. If you have to many records, you have to firstly deactivate foreign key, then change values as u need, then activate foreign key again. Try out this